# Hibernate config file parse exception

Tags: hibernate

Error message that i got during run the program

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:11)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 3 more
```

configuration file is that i use
DB connection setting is correct i sure about that..

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
              <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
              "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

              <hibernate-configuration>

              <session-factory>

                 <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


                  <!-- _________ Defining the Mapping Files ___________ -->

                  <mapping resource="Lecturer.hbm.xml" />

              </session-factory>
              </hibernate-configuration>
```

Main class for connection with hibernate.cfg.xml is  like this

```
public class SimpleTest {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    System.out.println("innnnnnnnnn");
                    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new
                       Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

                    Lecturer lecturer1 = new Lecturer();
                    lecturer1.setFirstName("Fatma");
                    lecturer1.setLastName("Meawad");

                    session.save(lecturer1);
                    tx.commit();

                }
              }

table and every think will be created
```

**Plese tell me where i wrong**

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: You haven't specified password in your config file. That might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your SimpleTest class,

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Comment: Still not work1!!! Actually problem in parsing hibernate.cfg.xml fileSessionFactory sessionFactory = new
                       Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  It will not return  sessionFactory  object...

Comment: post an image of your project structure. I want to know where you placed your hibernate configuration file

Comment: Hi Rishi,i put hibernate.cfg.xml file in src folder directly ...All file hibernate.cfg.xml,Lecturer.hbm.xml(mapping file),SimpleTest.java(main class) ,Pojo class in same packase src folder

Comment: try to delete these properties and try,
<property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

Comment: Still it give same error Rishi.... Is it possible that u share sample application in zip format.... I already work on hibernate on netbeans,but now i try in ecllipse.... So please if possible share sample application..I waiting for ur response

Comment: use this link [click here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide) 
It will show you how build it from the scratch in eclipse. Also you the download the sample project.

Comment: you might miss out the password field value in your configuration